# How to force a flex item to nowrap when parent has flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css

How can I force `.item2` to be placed in-line with `.item1` by only changing CSS of `.item2`? (I know that you would usually just change `.container` to `flex-direction: row`)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't unless your container is row, or column with a fixed height and wrap

Comment: Well, then do not use flex if its behavior does not suits your needs, look at grid. Can you explain why fex and flex-column? is there more than 2 items ?

Comment: @ G-Cyrillus: Yes, the entire markup is a bit more complicated. Essentially, I want users in the CMS Frontend to decide whether or not to place items in a column or row setup. Due to some architectural reasons it would just make my life a little easier if that could happen on item2 rather than the container.

Comment: okay, grid  + a class   can tell if the element is to be spanning one column (50% of width) or spaning two columns (the full row if template is set on 2columns). shall I answer with an exemple ? actually a single class would be needed , choose it for halfrow or full row :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks! You mean sth like grid-column: 1 / span 1 vs grid-column: 2 / span 1 ?

Comment: yes, i'll make an answer with a snippet to show you the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  background: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 0.25em;
}


/* here the class to use for a full row */
.itemNext {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: hotpink;
}



.item1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="itemNext">next Item </div>
  <div class="itemNext">next Item </div>
  <div class="item1 itemNext">next Item </div>
  <div class="item2 itemNext">next Item </div>
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="itemNext">next Item </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx! Really helpful!